# How do I set the driver's python version in spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using spark 1.4.0-rc2 so I can use python 3 with spark.  If I add `export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3` to my `.bashrc` file, I can run spark interactively with python 3.  However, if I want to run a standalone program in local mode, I get an error:

> Exception: Python in worker has different version 3.4 than that in
> driver 2.7, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions

How can I specify the version of python for the driver?  Setting `export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python3` didn't work.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to make sure the standalone project you're launching is launched with Python 3. If you are submitting your standalone program through spark-submit then it should work fine, but if you are launching it with python make sure you use python3 to start your app.

Also, make sure you have set your env variables in `./conf/spark-env.sh` (if it doesn't exist you can use `spark-env.sh.template` as a base.)

Comment: @Kevin - I am having same problem, could you please post your solution regarding what change you made in spark-evn.sh.

Comment: This is the right way of inducing PATH variables to Spark, instead of modifying `.bashrc`.

Comment: Why is using python 3 required @Holden?

Comment: Spark can run in python2, but in this case the user was trying to specify python3 in their question. Whichever Python version it is it needs to be done consistently.

Answer (score 97):

Setting both `PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python3` works for me.

I did this using export in my `.bashrc`. In the end, these are the variables I create:

```sh
export SPARK_HOME="$HOME/Downloads/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.4"
export IPYTHON=1
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython3
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"
```

I also followed this tutorial to make it work from within Ipython3 notebook:
http://ramhiser.com/2015/02/01/configuring-ipython-notebook-support-for-pyspark/

Comment: There is an error on spark 2.1 related to  "IPYTHON=1" option. The error messages is "IPYTHON and IPYTHON_OPTS are removed in Spark 2.0+. Remove these from the environment and set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS instead."

Comment: `PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3` sets the Python version of the workers, right?

Comment: If running from PyCharm, add `PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3; PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython3` to Run > Edit Configurations > {your_run_config} > Environment Variables.  To make these the default for all run configurations, update the Environment Variables for the desired template(s) under Run > Edit Configurations > Templates

Answer (score 31):

Helped in my case:

```py
import os

os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.5.1/"
os.environ["PYSPARK_PYTHON"]="/usr/local/bin/python3"
```

Comment: this works for me after set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON to the same value with PYSPARK_PYTHON.

Answer (score 15):

You can specify the version of Python for the driver by setting the appropriate environment variables in the `./conf/spark-env.sh` file. If it doesn't already exist, you can use the `spark-env.sh.template` file provided which also includes lots of other variables.

Here is a simple example of a `spark-env.sh` file to set the relevant Python environment variables:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This file is sourced when running various Spark programs.
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3       
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/ipython
```

In this case it sets the version of Python used by the workers/executors to Python3 and the driver version of Python to iPython for a nicer shell to work in.

If you don't already have a `spark-env.sh` file, and don't need to set any other variables, this one should do what you want, assuming that paths to the relevant python binaries are correct (verify with `which`). I had a similar problem and this fixed it.

Comment: How to run this file?

Comment: I had to rename spark-env.sh.template to spark-env.sh and then add to the tail of the file export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3 export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3. I had to figure out where my python3 was via which python3

Answer (score 13):

If you're running Spark in a larger organization and are unable to update the /spark-env.sh file, exporting the environment variables may not work.

You can add the specific Spark settings through the `--conf` option when submitting the job at run time.

```
pyspark --master yarn --[other settings]\ 
  --conf "spark.pyspark.python=/your/python/loc/bin/python"\ 
  --conf "spark.pyspark.driver.python=/your/python/loc/bin/python"
```

Answer (score 10):

I just faced the same issue and these are the steps that I follow in order to provide Python version. I wanted to run my PySpark jobs with Python 2.7 instead of 2.6.

1. Go to the folder where `$SPARK_HOME` is pointing to (in my case is `/home/cloudera/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/`)
2. Under folder `conf`, there is a file called `spark-env.sh`. **In case you have a file called `spark-env.sh.template` you will need to copy the file to a new file called `spark-env.sh`.**
3. Edit the file and write the next three lines

   > export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
   >
   > export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
   >
   > export SPARK_YARN_USER_ENV="PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python2.7"
4. Save it and launch your application again :)

**In that way, if you download a new Spark standalone version, you can set the Python version which you want to run PySpark to.**

Comment: Note the recommendation is to `cp` the file `spark-env.sh.template` as a new `spark-env.sh` and then change the new file rather than changing the template's name and content. The template is supposed to remain as a reference.

Comment: @et_l You are right, I just made a little modification to the answer taking your comment into account, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I came across the same error message and I have tried three ways mentioned above. I listed the results as a complementary reference to others.

1. Change the `PYTHON_SPARK` and `PYTHON_DRIVER_SPARK` value in `spark-env.sh` does not work for me.
2. Change the value inside python script using `os.environ["PYSPARK_PYTHON"]="/usr/bin/python3.5"`
   `os.environ["PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON"]="/usr/bin/python3.5"` does not work for me.
3. Change the value in `~/.bashrc` works like a charm~

Answer (score 3):

I was running it in IPython (as described in this [link by Jacek Wasilewski](http://thepowerofdata.io/configuring-jupyteripython-notebook-to-work-with-pyspark-1-4-0/) ) and was getting this exception; Added `PYSPARK_PYTHON` to the IPython kernel file and used jupyter notebook to run, and started working.

```
vi  ~/.ipython/kernels/pyspark/kernel.json

{
 "display_name": "pySpark (Spark 1.4.0)",
 "language": "python",
 "argv": [
  "/usr/bin/python2",
  "-m",
  "IPython.kernel",
  "--profile=pyspark",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],

 "env": {
  "SPARK_HOME": "/usr/local/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/",
  "PYTHONPATH": "/usr/local/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/:/usr/local/spark-1
.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip",
  "PYTHONSTARTUP": "/usr/local/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/shell.py
",
  "PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS": "--master spark://127.0.0.1:7077 pyspark-shell",
  "PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON":"ipython2",
   "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "python2"
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue on **standalone spark** in **windows**.
My version of fix is like this:
I had my environment variables setting as bellow

```
PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="pyspark-shell"
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook' pyspark
```

With this setting I executed an Action on pyspark and got the following exception:

```
Python in worker has different version 3.6 than that in driver 3.5, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions.
Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.
```

To check with which python version my *spark-worker* is using hit the following in the *cmd* prompt.

```
python --version
Python 3.6.3
```

which showed me *Python 3.6.3*. So clearly my *spark-worker* is using system python which is v3.6.3.

Now as I set my *spark-driver* to run jupyter by setting `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter` so I need to check the python version jupyter is using.

To do this check open *Anaconda Prompt* and hit

```
python --version
Python 3.5.X :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

Here got the jupyter python is using the *v3.5.x*. You can check this version also in any Notebook (Help->About).

Now I need to update the jupyter python to the version *v3.6.6*. To do that open up the *Anaconda Prompt* and hit

> conda search python

This will give you a list of available python versions in Anaconda. Install your desired one with

> conda install python=3.6.3

Now I have both of the Python installation of same version 3.6.3 Spark should not comply and it didn't when I ran an Action on Spark-driver. Exception is gone. 
Happy coding ...

Answer (score 1):

In case you only want to change the python version for current task, you can use following pyspark start command:

```
    PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/home/user1/anaconda2/bin/python PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/local/anaconda2/bin/python pyspark --master ..
```

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the below snippet:

```
#setting environment variable for pyspark in linux||ubuntu
#goto --- /usr/local/spark/conf
#create a new file named spark-env.sh copy all content of spark-env.sh.template to it
#then add below lines to it, with path to python

PYSPARK_PYTHON="/usr/bin/python3"
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="/usr/bin/python3"
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook --no-browser"
#i was running python 3.6 ||run - 'which python' in terminal to find the path of python
```

Comment: Please check the templates before posting.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, just forgot to activate my virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue working with pycharm and spark.
to fix this error I have followed given below steps to fix it.

1. Click on Run option in pycharm menu bar.
2. Click on Edit Configurations option.
3. Click on Environment Variables and write down given below lines
   as per your location.

   ```
   PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.6;
   PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.6;
   SPARK_HOME=/home/xxxxxx/Desktop/xxxx/spark
   ```

Comment: didnt help in mny case

Answer (score 0):

## Error

> "Exception: Python in worker has different version 2.6 than that in driver 
>   2.7, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions".

## Fix (for Cloudera environment)

- Edit this file: `/opt/cloudera/parcels/cdh5.5.4.p0.9/lib/spark/conf/spark-env.sh`
- Add these lines:

  ```
  export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python
  export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following environment

```
? python --version; ipython --version; jupyter --version
Python 3.5.2+
5.3.0
5.0.0
```

and the following aliases work well for me

```
alias pyspark="PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3 PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython ~/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/pyspark --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.5.0-spark2.1-s_2.11"    
alias pysparknotebook="PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3 PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook' ~/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/pyspark --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.5.0-spark2.1-s_2.11"
```

In the notebook, I set up the environment as follows

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this today at work. An admin thought it prudent to hard code Python 2.7 as the `PYSPARK_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh`. Needless to say this broke all of our jobs that utilize any other python versions or environments (which is > 90% of our jobs). @PhillipStich points out correctly that you may not always have write permissions for this file, as is our case. While setting the configuration in the `spark-submit` call is an option, another alternative (when running in yarn/cluster mode) is to set the `SPARK_CONF_DIR` environment variable to point to another configuration script. There you could set your PYSPARK_PYTHON and any other options you may need. A template can be found in the [spark-env.sh source code on github](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/conf/spark-env.sh.template).

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Ubuntu 18.04), I ran this code in terminal:

```
sudo vim ~/.bashrc
```

and then edited `SPARK_HOME` as follows:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/home/muser/programs/anaconda2019/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin
```

By doing so, my `SPARK_HOME` will refer to the `pyspark` package I installed in the `site-package`.

To learn how to use `vim`, go to [this](https://success.trendmicro.com/solution/1113864-editing-configuration-files-of-linux-based-products) link.

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*
```

The first row in this example shows the python3 symlink. To set it as the default python symlink run the following:

```
ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

then reload your shell.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on mac, use the following commands

```
export SPARK_HOME=`brew info apache-spark | grep /usr | tail -n 1 | cut -f 1 -d " "`/libexec
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$PYTHONPATH

export HADOOP_HOME=`brew info hadoop | grep /usr | head -n 1 | cut -f 1 -d " "`/libexec
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
```

If you are using another OS, check the following link:
https://github.com/GalvanizeDataScience/spark-install

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. The error i was getting said something similar to:

> my worker node has python3.10 while the driver has python3.11

What I had to do was to navigate to `/usr/bin/` and execute `ls -l`. I got the following output:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 Feb 12 19:50 python -> python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Oct 11  2021 python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  14K Oct 11  2021 python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.7K Oct 11  2021 python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Oct 11  2021 python2-config -> python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   10 Feb 12 19:50 python3 -> python3.10
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  15K Feb 12 19:50 python3.11
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3.2K Feb 12 19:50 python3.11-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   17 Feb 12 19:50 python3-config -> python3.11-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2.5K Apr  8  2023 python-argcomplete-check-easy-install-script
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  383 Apr  8  2023 python-argcomplete-tcsh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 Feb 12 19:50 python-config -> python3-config
```

Notice the line `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   10 Feb 12 19:50 python3 -> python3.10`

I realized that my python was pointing python3.10 even though I had python3.11 installed. If that's the case with you, then the following fix should work:

1. **Locate Python 3.11:** First, ensure that Python 3.11 is installed on your system. You can usually find it in `/usr/bin/` or `/usr/local/bin/`. Let's assume it's in `/usr/bin/python3.11`.
2. **Update the Symbolic Link:** Open a terminal and run:
   `sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.11 /usr/bin/python3`
3. **Verify the Update:** In the terminal, run: 
   `ls -l /usr/bin/python3` 

   This should show something like:
   `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root XX XXX XX:XX /usr/bin/python3 -> /usr/bin/python3.11`

   This indicates that python3 now points to Python 3.11.

Now, when you run your PySpark code, it should use Python 3.11 on both the worker nodes and the driver.