# Setting python in workers in SPARK YARN with anaconda

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I went through this post [setting python path for workers/drivers in standalone spark mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518362/how-do-i-set-the-drivers-python-version-in-spark). Apparently, the straightforward way is to direct PYSPARK_PATh environment variable in ./conf/spark-env.sh file located in the conf folder of spark such as /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/conf/ in my case. However, I was finding to repeat it for spark in YARN cluster mode. Tried playing around for quite some time. I found [this cloudera blog](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2016/02/making-python-on-apache-hadoop-easier-with-anaconda-and-cdh/) to add Anaconda package.

Now all that is left to do, is add the Anaconda path in the spark-env.sh file instead of the standard python path. It finally worked. Please share if there is a better/alternative way for python setup/update in SPARK and pyspark.

Comment: Apparently, I didn't need to do all this monkey business when I used spark-submit instead of pyspark interactive shell (both for YARN cluster mode). I am still wondering why that is the case.