# Python in worker has different version 3.6 than that in driver 3.7

Tags: python, macos, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to run PySpark from my local Jupyter notebook on my MacOS, I wrote this lines of code but got error in the collect function.

```py
data = [
    "Project",
    "Gutenberg’s",
    "Alice’s",
    "Adventures",
    "in",
    "Wonderland",
    "Project",
    "Gutenberg’s",
    "Adventures",
    "in",
    "Wonderland",
    "Project",
    "Gutenberg’s",
]
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
rdd2 = rdd.map(lambda x: (x, 1))
for element in rdd2.collect():
    print(element)
```

My error is below:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johanvu/opt/spark-2.4.3-bin-spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.8/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 267, in main
    ("%d.%d" % sys.version_info[:2], version))
Exception: Python in worker has different version 3.6 than that in driver 3.7, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions.Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.
```

How can I do to resolve it, I've spent hours and still have same problem?

Comment: you just need to install same version everywhere. the easiest is to install 3.6 on driver (= on your mac)

Comment: how to do it please ? where is the driver and the worker?

Comment: driver is your computer - worker is the cluster you're connecting to

Comment: ok i will do do you know how to downgrade the 3.7 to 3.6 please?

Comment: uninstall 3.7 and install 3.6

Comment: i was not able to resolve it . I should upgrade my spark python. ? i added this rows in the profile **export PYSPARK_PYTHON="/Users/user1/anaconda3/bin/python"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="/Users/user1/anaconda3/bin/python"
**

Comment: im still gotting the same error :'(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the driver's python version in spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518362/how-do-i-set-the-drivers-python-version-in-spark)

Comment: no :/ always same problem