# Getting an error for PySpark when I try to run .take()

Tags: python, windows, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to learning py spark so forgive the very basic not detailed question. I am trying to sc to read a .tsv file and then parse that file. However after reading the file when I try to do .take() on it, it gives me the following error, which I cannot understand. I am running it on windows. Below is the code:

```
print("TEST 1")
rdd = sc.textFile(tsv_path)
print("TEST 2", rdd.take(1))
rdd = rdd.map(lambda line: (line.split('\t')[0], line.split('\t')[1], line.split('\n')[2]))
print("TEST 3")

rdd = rdd.collect()
print("TEST 4")

print("Test:", rdd.take(1))
print(type(rdd))
```

And here is the error I am getting:

```
TEST 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-231258a7df7b> in <module>
----> 1 outdegree("graph.tsv", "q1_out/")

<ipython-input-4-c31bb2bfe1ae> in outdegree(tsv_path, out_dir)
      5     print("TEST 1")
      6     rdd = sc.textFile(tsv_path)
----> 7     print("TEST 2", rdd.take(1))
      8     rdd = rdd.map(lambda line: (line.split('\t')[0], line.split('\t')[1], line.split('\n')[2]))
      9     print("TEST 3")

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py in take(self, num)
   1566 
   1567             p = range(partsScanned, min(partsScanned + numPartsToTry, totalParts))
-> 1568             res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
   1569 
   1570             items += res

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py in runJob(self, rdd, partitionFunc, partitions, allowLocal)
   1225         # SparkContext#runJob.
   1226         mappedRDD = rdd.mapPartitions(partitionFunc)
-> 1227         sock_info = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
   1228         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, mappedRDD._jrdd_deserializer))
   1229 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1307 
   1308         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1309         return_value = get_return_value(
   1310             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1311 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (LAPTOP-BI16OVUR executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 481, in main
RuntimeError: Python in worker has different version 3.9 than that in driver 3.8, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions. Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: This might discussion should help [how-do-i-set-the-drivers-python-version-in-spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518362/how-do-i-set-the-drivers-python-version-in-spark/31317634)

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you have different python versions on driver and worker.
The driver and workers need to have the same python version.
In your driver machine, you need to use Python version 3.9 instead of 3.8

Locate Python version 3.9 on your driver/workers and export the following variable

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.9
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.9
```

Comment: So i was able to do this in the nootbook using: 
%set_env PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.9
%set_env PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.9

But, I still have that first error:
An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem , I was using pip installed pyspark library in conda virtual env as well as the standalone spark in my pc .

To solve the problem -

1. I deleted the pyspark library from my virutal env
2. used `conda install -c conda-forge findspark` to install findspark in my virtual env
3. used
   `import findspark`
   `findspark.init()`
   in my code file to connect local spark with virutal env

And the error was gone