Pyspark job failing when trying to write, says worker versions are different but the versions match
The write option seems to be failing when it gets to the write command, before that it is able to pass the pandas dataframe. before that wit seems to be creating and applying methods fine. The error that I keep getting when trying to write is: [PYTHON_VERSION_MISMATCH] Python in worker has different version (3, 11) than that in driver 3.9, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions
The version is 3.9 in the editor and the versions of pandas and pyspark should be compatible so I don't know where the issue is coming from.
I've tried specifying the driver version in the spark constructor to 3.9, I've exported the driver environment variables to be 3.9 and that hasn't solved the issue. Python version is 3.9, pandas 1.5.3, and pyspark 3.50. I tried with 3.11 and that wouldn't run because pyspark isn't supported/won't import
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local[*]") \
    .appName("Test Connection") \
    .config('spark.jars', '/usr/local/bin/postgresql-42.7.3.jar') \
    .config("spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON", "/usr/local/bin/python3.9") \
    .config("spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON", "/usr/local/bin/python3.9") \
    .config("spark.pyspark.python", "/usr/local/bin/python3.9") \
    .config("spark.pyspark.driver.python", "/usr/local/bin/python3.9") \
    .getOrCreate()

    df = pandas.read_csv(data_file)
    df['title'] = df['title'].apply(lambda title: decode_from_base64(title))

    df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(df)
    df_spark =       df_spark.withColumn("snapshot_time(UTC)",df_spark["snapshot_time(UTC)"].cast(TimestampType()))

    df_spark_schema = spark.createDataFrame(df_spark.rdd, schema=TABLE_SCHEMA)
    df_spark_schema = df_spark.withColumnRenamed("snapshot_time(UTC)", "snapshot_time_utc")
    df_spark_schema.write.jdbc(url=f'jdbc:postgresql://{ip_addr}:{port}/{db}', table=main_table,       properties=connection, mode='append') #breaks here


Can you verify /usr/local/bin/python3.9 exists both on driver and executors? Also, try setting PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON as env variables before the script execution. These kind of variables need to be set before you run the program itself that creates the spark session, because the moment you run above script, your python is already chosen. Or, depending how you run this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50953703/3433323

@mkaran Yea it looks like that was the issue. I assumed that running with python3.9 would set those drivers on its own at runtime
